# Given text file path, how to Fetch and Store TextFile Contents into DataTable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given a FilePath how to retrieve contents from the file and store all contents into a column in blob data type.

Ex: Input: **"F:\Data\sample.txt"** 
    Output Logic: **Get Contents of "F:\Data\sample.txt" and store it in Table Column**

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/

Comment: I actually upvoted this question. I was going to need to do this in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally i got the answer, this works for me

```
CREATE TABLE #tempfile (line varchar(8000))
EXEC ('bulk INSERT #tempfile FROM ''D:\New Text Document.txt'' ')
SELECT * FROM #tempfile
DROP TABLE #tempfile
```

Comment: @EonRustedduPlessis ha ha but finally i got it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have.

```
create table #ORStable (doclen bigint, doc varbinary(max))

insert into #ORStable
select len(bulkcolumn), *
from
openrowset(bulk 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Notes\master.txt', SINGLE_BLOB)  --filepath here
as r

select *
from #ORStable
```

All I could find... Closest you are going to get to your answer
[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/a91e4a05-25b2-449a-9d51-08e54fef702c/)